# How to use edit Mask in Grid Cell?

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, devexpress

i have a DevExpress Grid and want to set up an edit Mask on each cell of a column. So that the user can type a value in this cell and my programm check it via edit Mask RegEx. I know i can set up a textbox control on each cell and there i can use the mask. But this dont work with other requirements i have to observe.
In my cell are all values allowed which x<10. I want that if the user type 99 my cell automaticly makes 9,9 like a editMask. Is there an Event which fires after each value typed into cell? Then i can programm this by my self and dont need Mask.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to only do this editting once the user is finished editting a cell, i.e. a user shouldn't be interrupted in the middle of typing. The event that you want to use is `DataGridView.CellValueChanged`, and you can use `DataGridView.SelectedCell` property to find the editted cell, and you can get/set the value accordingly. Hopefully that answers your question.